# Optimising SQL query on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, profiling, pgadmin

I have this sql query which I am trying to optimise, total time it is taking is about 12 seconds. So I used explain analyse and on top it shows nested loop, its cost and actual time, I know it is an algorithm that it uses to iterate over rows, which are 145854. I have tried indexing but it does not seems to affect much even though the explain analyse shows it does use it, Please if anyone can suggest any changes in query. Please see the attached query and the result it shows

```
explain analyse 
    SELECT 
           "feedback_option"."feedback_id" AS Col2,
           "feedback_option"."feedback_created_at" AS Col3,
           "feedback_option"."feedback_stage_id" AS Col4,
           "feedback_option"."option_id" AS Col5,
           "feedback_option"."other_text" AS Col6,
           "feedback_option"."duration" AS Col7,
           "feedback_option"."back_counter" AS Col8,
           "feedback_option"."is_spam" AS Col9,
           "feedback_option"."dx" AS Col10,
           "feedback_option"."dy" AS Col11,
           "feedback_option"."dz" AS Col12,
           "feedback_option"."created_at" AS Col13,
           "feedback_option"."ts" AS Col14,
           "feedback_option"."contact_name" AS Col15,
           "feedback_option"."contact_number" AS Col16,
           NULLIF(TRIM("feedback_option"."other_text"), '') AS "annotated_other_text",
           (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AS "created_at_tz",
           EXTRACT('year' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_year",
           EXTRACT('isoyear' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_iso_year",
           EXTRACT('quarter' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_quarter",
           EXTRACT('month' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_month",
           EXTRACT('week' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_week",
           EXTRACT('dow' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') + 1 AS "created_at_tz_week_day",
           EXTRACT('day' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_day",
           EXTRACT('hour' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_hour",
           EXTRACT('minute' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_minute",
           EXTRACT('second' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "created_at_tz_second",
           EXTRACT('dow' FROM (feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') + 1 AS "week_day",
           ((feedback.created_at at time zone 'Asia/Karachi'))::time AS "created_time"
      FROM "feedback_option"
     INNER JOIN "question_option"
        ON ("feedback_option"."option_id" = "question_option"."id")
     INNER JOIN "question"
        ON ("question_option"."question_id" = "question"."id")
     INNER JOIN "feedback"
        ON ("feedback_option"."feedback_id" = "feedback"."id")
     INNER JOIN "questionnaire"
        ON ("feedback"."questionnaire_id" = "questionnaire"."id")
     INNER JOIN "questionnaires_questionnairerole"
        ON ("questionnaire"."id" = "questionnaires_questionnairerole"."questionnaire_id")
     WHERE (NULLIF(TRIM("feedback_option"."other_text"), '') IS NOT NULL 
       AND "question"."kind" = 'COM' 
       AND "feedback"."processed" = true 
       AND "feedback"."division_id" IN (
           SELECT U0."id" 
           FROM "division" U0 
           WHERE U0."id" IN ( 
               WITH RECURSIVE division_descendents AS ( 
                   SELECT id, parent_id 
                   FROM division 
                   WHERE id IN (2) 
                   UNION SELECT child.id, child.parent_id 
                   FROM division AS child 
                   INNER JOIN division_descendents AS parent ON parent.id = child.parent_id 
                   WHERE child.is_active = True 
               ) 
               SELECT id 
               FROM division_descendents 
           )
       ) 
       AND "feedback"."organization_id" = 2 
       AND "questionnaires_questionnairerole"."role_id" = 173 
       AND "feedback"."organization_id" = 2 
       AND "feedback"."questionnaire_id" = 183 
       AND "feedback"."group_id" = 1 
       AND "feedback"."processed" = true
    )
```

Following is the query plan it shows

[image: Query plan Image]

Comment: Please post the query plan as formatted text, not images.  Especially not as images which have been truncated on both dimensions.

Comment: When you add the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this query in plain text, could you also add the ddl for the tables involved? Including the indexes

Answer (score 0):

When we are use functions after the where command on conditions, example `lower(name)='tom'` then DB can't use indexes. Recommended use expression index for these situations. example: `CREATE INDEX test_a2_idx ON test USING btree (lower(name))`
You have one of these. `WHERE (NULLIF(TRIM("feedback_option"."other_text"), '') IS NOT NULL`

Inside the `IN` command if your subquery results many records then recommended use `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`. For Example: use

```
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

instead of

```
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select id from t2)
```

If you are always using `child.is_active = True` with your other conditions on your queries, you can use partial index for optimizing and decreasing index size. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX division_parentid_idx ON division USING btree (parent_id) where is_active = true
```

If possible, try to apply above options and then see the result. I guess there must be a difference.

Comment: For partial indexing please see to this too, `"feedback"."processed" = true`